# How do I add an external javascript file into discourse?

Tags: javascript, file, discourse

I have a javascript file that I would to add to discourse, but I am not sure how. Am I required to create a plugin to include a js file or can I include the file in the source code? Either way, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is to embed, in every Discourse page, a  tag linking to an external resource, you need to do the following:

1. Create a theme component and include it to all your themes
2. In your theme component, click "Edit CSS/HTML"
3. In the `</head>` section, enter your `<script src="..."></script>` code and click "Save"
4. In Discourse setting `content_security_policy_script_src`, add the full url of the script

The full doc is [here](https://meta.discourse.org/t/mitigate-xss-attacks-with-content-security-policy/104243).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by adding the following code `<script async src="url-here" data-url="url-here"></script>` Into the  `</head>` section of /admin/customize/themes

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
  <script src="**URL**"></script> under the head section.

    The URL of the external script file.
Possible values:

An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/example.js")
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="/scripts/example.js")
```